# Error connecting to mysql on another computer in a C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm creating a desktop application using Visual studio and C# that uses MySQL.
I want to use the exe on another computer which is on the same network (the computer jas the .Net framework but no MySql install).

I am allowing MySql to be connected to remotely(by "from Host: %") on the system where my database resides.

My connection string is:

```
"SERVER=fullComputerName;" + "DATABASE=dbTest;" + "UID=abcd;" + "PASSWORD=myPassword;"
```

When I run the application on another computer on same network, it gives me the error

> your connection attempt failed for user 'abcd' from your host to server at 'fullComputerName:3306'.

I am not sure can we do something like that or I always need one computer to be server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to open your firewall on port 3306 for the machine running MySQL.

Opening that port up is necessary for the remote connection to work correctly.

Also are you able to connect to the remote database from other machines?

Comment: no i haven't check on any other machines. But my concern is that the system on which my MySql running is not a server , it is just a computer on same network. will it work like that? I ll check firewall..

Comment: The MySql Instance doesn't need to be on an actual server machine, it can be on any kind of machine, XP, Vista, *nix.  The machine it is on just needs to be something the other machine can access.  What type of machine is the MySQL instance running on?

Comment: Hey Thank you .. it worked by opening port. I am working on windows xp.

Comment: Awesome, that should be all you need to do.